# Issue with html pentaho report in openerp

Tags: pentaho-design-studio

i have integrated the pentaho report designer with openerp,and able to generate reports from openerp with pdf,html,csv.But when i click on pdf report i able to see graphs and charts whereas in HTML ther is no graph and charts.Any solution would be helpful.

Another question, is there any plugin for adding openerp datastore in pentaho bi-server like in report designer we can add openerp datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the output format you are choosing supports graphs and charts.  When using your report inside the designer and choosing to preview as HTML, are the graphs and charts all rendered?

In relation to the second question, the OpenERP Datastore is no longer an addon that is post installed, but is included in the designer and engine by default (since version 5.1, I believe).  I don't know if the Pentaho bi-server differs in its sources, but it may be worth checking again with the latest version.